# How can segue between tableview with parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How to build applications such as music applications using the parse . At first UITableView used to display the album , and the second UITableView used to display songs, based on the selected album , the first UITableView . Thanks for help.

Comment: What are you storing on Parse?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should create the "album" and "song" model objects by subclassing PFObject (see [Parse Doc](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses)) and pass the "album" object from the first table view controller to the second when the user tap a cell.

For this action you can use one of this 2 methods :

- Keep using your segue and implement "performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:" in which you add your "album" object to the second view controller (the one which will display the songs)
- Implement the table's "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" delegate method instead of the segue and do something similar to the first option

You should have a look at the Parse samples ([tutorials](https://parse.com/tutorials))